# onBitmapLoaded called with empty bitmap android

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

Here is the code:

```
           Target mTarget = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
                mBinding.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {

            }
        };
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUri).into(mTarget);
```

onBitmapLoaded method getting called with empty bitmap. It is very random, I guess its not working when I am loading image from memory card instead of phone memory.

Any idea?

Comment: what exactly `empty bitmap` means?

Comment: its giving me bitmap ="";

Comment: No I need to do some extra work after that

Comment: what is Target ??

Comment: Bitmap can't be "". It is not a string. It can be null, it can be totally transparent, can have size 0x0, but it can't be ""

Comment: @mrid, `Target ` is a listener for the request. It is common thing to use it if you need to pre-process downloaded image before using

Comment: @VladMatvienko oh okay, thanks for the info

Comment: `but inside it variable are null` could you please elaborate this to be more correct in English? It has too many mistakes to understand.

Comment: getting bitmap object with following values -
mImagePath=null
mNinePatchhunk=null
mDensity=480
mIsMutable=true
mRecycled=false
mHeight=4128
mWidth=2322

Comment: that image looks ok, having no problems except the size. It is too large for some devices. You shouldn't use it. You should pre-scale it before using.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso holds Target instance with a weak reference, So your Target seems to be garbage collected.

Try using:

```
Target mTarget; // define the Target beforehand


mTarget = new Target() {
   ...
};

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUri).into(mTarget);
```

Comment: this is not the case.